# NestedScrollView с несколькими RecyclerView или один RecyclerView с разными ViewType?

Tags: android, recyclerview, nested-scrollview

Во многих приложениях есть экраны, в которых есть прокручиваемый список, и в этом списке есть секции с горизонтальным прокручиванием, как например в Delivery. Необходимо сделать подобный экран, и стал вопрос как лучше это сделать, с помощью `NestedScrollView` и в нем несколько `RecyclerView` или один `RecyclerView` с разными `ViewType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однозначного решения нет. Однако решение без NestedScrollView при прочих равных, хоть и будет сложнее в реализации, будет производительнее, из-за переиспользования ячеек и их ленивой загрузки для отображаения. Если же всё вышеописанное на один экран умещается - то никакого выигрыша не будет. Но выигрыш по производительности можно будет получить только для горизонтальных списков, если они - RecyclerView.и в них больше элементов, чем умещается на экран.